# Mixed results implementing letsencrypt server cert

Tags: curl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, tornado, lets-encrypt

Summary:

Why is macOS `curl` able to fetch my letsencrypt service, but other tools/OS aren't able to verify the certificate?

---

I have a tiny REST service implemented in tornado using letsencrypt certs running on a Ubuntu 18.04 box. I setup my server as such:

```
sslContext = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
certFile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.com/cert.pem'
keyFile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.com/privkey.pem'
sslContext.load_cert_chain(certFile, keyFile)
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options=sslContext)
```

When I use `curl -v` on my MacBookPro, things look good:

```
curl -v https://my.server.com:8899/rest
*   Trying aa.bb.cc.dd...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.server.com (aa.bb.cc.dd) port 8899 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=my.server.com
*  start date: Jan 26 15:27:27 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 15:27:27 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "my.server.com" matched cert's "my.server.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
```

But when I try the same on a different Ubuntu box (2 of them actually, as well as two Debian buster/testing boxes), I get errors:

```
curl -v https://my.server.com:8899/rest
*   Trying aa.bb.cc.dd...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.server.com (aa.bb.cc.dd) port 8899 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

My goal was to use the python `requests` module to query this API, but I haven't been able to make that work anywhere, including the macOS box. Even when I copied the latest cacert.pem from the certifi sources.

Comment: (1) you aren't configuring to send the intermediate aka chain cert, although depending on how python defaults the truststore it might get added implicitly. Try `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -showcerts` to see if your server is serving the chain cert or not; I don't _think_ python SSL server depends on SNI, but to be safe if OpenSSL below 1.1.1 add `-servername $hostname`. Or if your server is public use the automated checkers at ssllabs.com (Qualys) or sslshopper.com or similar.

Comment: (2) failing that, it _might_ be the root. The IdenTrust "DST Root CA X3" (currently) used by LE, although published, wasn't very widely trusted until a few years ago. Check the truststores used by each client you care about.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, you got me going in the right direction. After comparing the output of that command on macOS and Ubuntu (which were similar), I dug around in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/...` directory and happened to take a peek in the `README` file. Wherein it states `fullchain.pem: the certificate file used in most server software.` and `cert.pem: will break many server configurations, and should not be used without reading further documentation (see link below).` I changed to `fullchain.pem` and it now works. Not sure what to do with this question now...

Comment: @TravisGriggs, I guess write up a detailed answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to pay attention is these comments in the `README` file:

> fullchain.pem: the certificate file used in most server software.

and

> cert.pem: will break many server configurations, and should not be
>   used without reading further documentation (see link below).

Bottom line. Use fullchain.pem